# Is it possible to add a datePicker into a reusable cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker, iboutlet

[App photo for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPav1.png)

So I have been trying to add a datePicker through that textfield in the photo above. I know how to create the datePicker itself, but I just cannot figure out how to connect it. I have created a cocoa touch class file for the textfield, but cannot connect the the textField from storyboard to that file. I have also tried changing the class in the identity inspector but it would not let me. I am sure I am missing something I just honestly do not know what.

Answer (score 0):

it is what are you looking for I think!

```
//Picker Creation
let currentDate = Date()
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .date
picker.setDate(currentDate, animated: false)
picker.tintColor = UIColor.white
picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

//Set DatePicker for input view in textField
let field = UITextField()
field.inputView = picker
```